# Unable to display data from PDO mysql script which auto generates table layout based on database structure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The issue i am having is with the below piece of code (the code from the whole page is included below), the entire page is designed to look at a mysql database and give a list of all the tables (which works), then you choose a table from the drop down list (which works) underneath it will list all the rows in that table with a header row with each column named as per the name of the column in the database.

The issue is the below script lists the number of rows correctly based on the number of rows in the table but none of the row data is returned, i have tried my best to get the data to be displayed in the rows but they are just appearing blank, could someone advise what i have done wrong ?

Just as a note i am currently converting the script from running on an sqlite database to mysql just trying to get past this problem before continuing with converting this script.

Thanks

```
<?
$alltables3=$db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name",PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$columns = array();
while($result3=$alltables3->fetch()){
$columns[] = $result3[0];
}
// Display * from SELECTED TABLE
$alltables4=$db->query("SELECT * FROM $table_name",PDO::FETCH_NUM);
while($result4=$alltables4->fetch()){

//echo $result4[0].'<br/>';

            echo "<tr>";
//          echo "<form name='delete' action='index.php?ID=$row[0]' method='post'>";
            $test = $result4[0];
        foreach ($columns as $col) 

            echo "<td>" . $row[$col] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 0px solid transparent'><tr><td><a id='alink' href='index.php?table=$table_name&ED=ED&ID=$test' class='button orange small'>Edit</a></td>";
            echo "<td><form action='' name='Delete' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='table' value='$table_name' size='10'><input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$test' size='10'><input type='submit' name='Delete' class='button red small' value='Delete'>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</td></tr></table></td>";
    }
            echo "</tr>";

?>
            </tbody>
```

For the sake of competition i have included below all the code for the entire page which includes the code above

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
</head>
</body>
<?
   if($_SESSION['LOGGED_IN']=="YES")
   {
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// SET DEFAULT TABLE TO BE LISTED IN TABLES

// SET TABLE VARIABLE
   $table_name = $_GET['table'];
// DISPLAY ONLY THE FIRST TABLE

if (empty($_GET['table'])) {

    //$db = new SQLite3('../data.db');
      include('db.php');
/*
    $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name LIMIT 1;");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
        if ($table['name'] != "sqlite_sequence") {
            $table_name = $table['name'];
            $_GET['table'] = $table['name'];
        }
    }
*/
} 

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?>
<body>
<br>
    <div id="tablewrapper">
        <div id="tableheader">
        <div class="search">
<form>

<select name='table' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value="">All Tables</option>




<?php
// Display all sqlite table names
$alltables=$db->query("SHOW TABLES",PDO::FETCH_NUM);

while($result=$alltables->fetch()){

//echo $result[0].'<br/>';
//echo "<option value='".$result[0]."'>".$result[0]."</option>";


if ($result[0] == $_GET['table']) {

                            $table_name_2 = ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', $result[0])));
                        echo "<option selected='selected' value='".$result[0]."'>".$table_name_2."</option>";
                        }
                    else
                {
                            $table_name_2 = ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', $result[0])));
                        echo "<option value='".$result[0]."'>".$table_name_2."</option>";
                }


}
?>
</select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>


            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <select id="columns" onchange="sorter.search('query')">

<?
$alltables=$db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name",PDO::FETCH_NUM);

while($result=$alltables->fetch()){

//echo $result[0].'<br/>';
//       echo "<th><h3>" . $result[0] . "</h3></th>";
//}
        $table_name_header = ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', $result[0])));
        //echo "<th><h3>" . $table_name_header . "</h3></th>";
        echo "<option value='".$result[0]."'>".$table_name_header."</option>";

}
?>

                </select>
                <input type="text" id="query" onkeyup="sorter.search('query')" />
            </div>
            <span class="details">
                <div>Records <span id="startrecord"></span>-<span id="endrecord"></span> of <span id="totalrecords"></span></div>
                <div><a href="javascript:sorter.reset()">Reset</a></div>
            </span>
        </div>
            <?
// DELETE ROW FROM DATABASE

if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {

    $ID_delete = $_POST['ID'];

// INSERT VALUES INTO DATABASE
$db->exec('DELETE FROM ' . $table_name . ' WHERE ID = "' . $ID_delete . '"');
echo "Details have been Deleted";
echo "<br><br>";


} else { 
//echo "NO ID"; 
} 

?>
<?
// INSERT NEW ROW INTO DATABASE

if (isset($_POST['Add'])) {

// KEY DATA (TABLE COLUMN NAME)
$string_key = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $string_key .= $key.',';
}
$string_key_final2 = str_replace(',table,Add,', '', $string_key);
$string_key_final = str_replace(',', ', ', $string_key_final2);

$string_value = '';

// KEY DATA (TABLE VARIABLES TO BE INSERTED)
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $string_value .= $value.',';
}

$string_value_1 = str_replace(',' . $table_name . ',Add,', '', $string_value);
$string_value_2 = "'" . str_replace("," , "', '", $string_value_1) . "'";
$string_value_final = str_replace('' , '', $string_value_2);

// INSERT VALUES INTO DATABASE
$db->exec('INSERT INTO ' . $table_name . '('. $string_key_final .') VALUES (' . $string_value_final . ')');

echo "Details have been Added";
echo "<br><br>";
}

?>


        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table" class="tinytable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
<?php // Display all sqlite column names for chosen table

$alltables=$db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name",PDO::FETCH_NUM);

while($result=$alltables->fetch()){

        $table_name_header = ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', $result[0])));
        echo "<th><h3>" . $table_name_header . "</h3></th>";


}?>
<th><h3>Controls</h3></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>


<?
$alltables3=$db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name",PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$columns = array();
while($result3=$alltables3->fetch()){
$columns[] = $result3[0];
}
// Display * from SELECTED TABLE
$alltables4=$db->query("SELECT * FROM $table_name",PDO::FETCH_NUM);
while($result4=$alltables4->fetch()){

//echo $result4[0].'<br/>';

            echo "<tr>";
//          echo "<form name='delete' action='index.php?ID=$row[0]' method='post'>";
            $test = $result4[0];
        foreach ($columns as $col) 

            echo "<td>" . $row[$col] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='border: 0px solid transparent'><tr><td><a id='alink' href='index.php?table=$table_name&ED=ED&ID=$test' class='button orange small'>Edit</a></td>";
            echo "<td><form action='' name='Delete' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='table' value='$table_name' size='10'><input type='hidden' name='ID' value='$test' size='10'><input type='submit' name='Delete' class='button red small' value='Delete'>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</td></tr></table></td>";
    }
            echo "</tr>";

?>
            </tbody>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <thead>
                <tr>



<?php // Display form details to add new row

    $tablesquery = $db->query("PRAGMA table_info($table_name)");

    while ($table = $tablesquery->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {

//      $table_name_add = $table['name'];
//        echo "<th><h3>" . "<input type='text' name='$table_name_add' size='10'>" . "</h3></th>";

if ($table['name'] == "ID") {

        echo "<th><h3>&nbsp;</h3></th>";

} else {

            $table_name_add = $table['name'];
        echo "<th><h3>" . "<input type='text' name='$table_name_add' size='10'>" . "</h3></th>";

}        

} 
?>
<th><h3><input type='hidden' name='table' value='<? echo $table_name ?>' size='10'><input type="submit" name="Add" class="button green small" value="Add" />


</h3></th>
<!--
<input type="image" src="images/login.jpg" alt="Submit Form" /> 
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="Submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
-->

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </form>            


        </table>
        <div id="tablefooter">
          <div id="tablenav">
                <div>
                    <img src="images/first.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1,true)" />
                    <img src="images/previous.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(-1)" />
                    <img src="images/next.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="First Page" onclick="sorter.move(1)" />
                    <img src="images/last.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Last Page" onclick="sorter.move(1,true)" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="pagedropdown"></select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="javascript:sorter.showall()">view all</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tablelocation">
                <div>
                    <select onchange="sorter.size(this.value)">
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                    <span>Entries Per Page</span>
                </div>
                <div class="page">Page <span id="currentpage"></span> of <span id="totalpages"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var sorter = new TINY.table.sorter('sorter','table',{
        headclass:'head',
        ascclass:'asc',
        descclass:'desc',
        evenclass:'evenrow',
        oddclass:'oddrow',
        evenselclass:'evenselected',
        oddselclass:'oddselected',
        paginate:true,
        size:10,
        colddid:'columns',
        currentid:'currentpage',
        totalid:'totalpages',
        startingrecid:'startrecord',
        endingrecid:'endrecord',
        totalrecid:'totalrecords',
        hoverid:'selectedrow',
        pageddid:'pagedropdown',
        navid:'tablenav',
        sortcolumn:0,
<?
/*
        sortdir:1,
        sum:[8],
        avg:[6,7,8,9],
        columns:[{index:7, format:'%', decimals:1},{index:8, format:'$', decimals:0}],
*/
?>
        init:true
    });
  </script>

<? include 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching a numeric-keyed array:

```
$alltables4=$db->query("SELECT * FROM $table_name",PDO::FETCH_NUM);
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But then you're using the column names in your display code:

```
        echo "<td>" . $row[$col] . "</td>";
                           ^^^^
```

e.g. you're doing `echo $row['id']` instead of `echo $row[0]`. Or fetch an associative array, so you can do `$row[$col]` as-is.

Comment: cool thanks, how would you best suggest this be resolved if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: like I said, fetch an associative array instead: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`